# How to correctly pack my electron/react app that uses electron features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

### Summary

I want to pack my (working) electron-react app into a mac app file. It builds fine, but when I start it up, I simply get following error:

> Error: ENOENT, electron not found in .../potoo/dist/mac/potoo.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar

### Setup

- I use electron with react.
- `npm-start` works fine, electron is started and contains my application. It also can access electron specific eatures like "ipcRenderer"
- React Content is placed in the `src/`-Folder, while electron content is placed in `electron/`
- I pack the project by using `npm run build && npm run electron-webpack && npm run pack` To first build the react project and then pack it into an app.

The electron app starts up and renders the window as desired, but when the dom should load, it fails by displaying an error message (see above).

### What I think it is

Since I load the ipcRenderer by calling `const x = window.require('electron')`, something fails to load the electron module correctly. I can't move electron to the dependencies though, it only allows it to be used as devDependency.

I don't know how to reference electron features correctly since it works fine in dev mode.

### Additional Information

#### Package.json

```
{
    "name": "potoo",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": {...},
    "description": "...",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "./",
    "main": "electron/main.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.54",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "nedb": "^1.8.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5",
        "uuid": "^8.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nf start -p 3000",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "electron": "electron .",
        "electron-start": "node src/start-react",
        "react-start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start -c.extraMetadata.main=main/main.js",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "npm run build && build",
        "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
        "compile": "electron-webpack"
    },
    "electronWebpack": {
        "commonSourceDirectory": "common",
        "main": {
            "sourceDirectory": "electron"
        },
        "renderer": {
            "sourceDirectory": null
        }
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.electron.electron-with-create-react-app",
        "win": {
            "icon": "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/designer-skills/128/react-256.png"
        },
        "directories": {
            "buildResources": "assets"
        },
        "extends": null
    },
    "files": [
        "./build/**/*"
    ],
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
        "electron": "^9.2.0",
        "electron-builder": "^22.8.0",
        "electron-webpack": "^2.8.2"
    }
}
```

#### Files

````
├── .DS_Store
├── .eslintrc.json
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── node_modules/
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── electron
│   ├── database.module.js
│   ├── main.js
│   └── potoo.db
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── .DS_Store
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── src
│   ├── components
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   ├── serviceWorker.ts
│   ├── setupTests.ts
│   └── start-react.js
└── tsconfig.json
```
````